# Wine for ubuntu doesn't detect webcam

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, webcam, wine

I'm using wine in order to install and run yahoo messenger on ubuntu(9.10) But it does not detect the webcam. Not unlike in skype that it can detect(skype not run through wine).
What do I do in order for it to detect the cam?

Answer (score 1):

if the webcam is usb wine does not support usb

Comment: Its built in...

Comment: might worth looking at winehq to see how supported yahoo messenger is in wine